# SCIM receive users' group id(s) in response

Tags: azure-active-directory, scim

I'm implementing SCIM 2.0. I can provision and deprovision users. The thing is, i need to receive users' group id(s) to use it in my app. But i don't receive any group id. 
Is there a way to receive any group id (in user response, not group).
For now i'm testing it with Azure Active Directory. Maybe i should change the mappings? I already tried to grab the id of the group for a user but there is no option to select it in the mapping..

Comment: Why do you want to get users' group id(s)? Are you trying to get the user's role based on the groups?

Comment: @AllenWu my app is based on communities/subcommunities. I subscribe users in communities/subcommunities with SSO based on the group id in Azure. i want to deprovision users from the right community using the group id also

Answer (score 0):

In Azure AD group memberships are a property on the group, not the user. You'll need to provision the group objects across (to the /groups endpoint) and the memberships should be represented in the members property of each group, with each value of members being the ID value of a member user/object.

Azure AD doesn't have functionality today to include group membership information as a property of a user, nor am I aware of it being on any roadmaps.

Comment: So what you're saying is that at the top level, you're provisioning a client's groups and at the same time provisioning each group's members because members are a property of the group? In reading the spec, the attributes you get with the members on a group do not contain everything you need to provision that user. How then do you accomplish provisioning a client's group AND users so that the service provider matches the structure of the client?

Comment: Create users first, then add the created users as members. They're two separate objects and the members attribute is an establishment of a link between the user and the group.

Comment: That makes sense but is that how SCIM defines the protocol or is that just how Azure AD does it? (By that I'm talking about creating all the users first, then provisioning the groups, taking into account the members list that comes with each group.)

Comment: To the best of my knowledge that's how the SCIM RFC breaks it up. I was looking at something related to groups in the RFC yesterday and came across users having a "groups" attribute - which was news to me. It has a mutability of readOnly though and is just a mechanism to list which groups a user is a member of.

Based on my interpretation the SCIM RFC is pretty clear - groups have a fairly limited number of attributes, as defined in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7643#section-4.2 (+ the Common Attributes defined in 3.1).

Comment: Given the existence of that "groups" attribute in the core schema for users, it seems like it's possible from a protocol standpoint to build logic around consuming values in the user's "groups" attribute. Azure AD doesn't support this today, though. I'm not sure if any other IdPs do, either.

Comment: Thanks for the insight!